# Basic Binary to Decimal Conversion Program not working (Python)

Tags: python, binary

I tried writing a basic program that converted binary to decimal. However, it's not working. Where did I go wrong? What am I missing. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
n=int(raw_input(' '))

while n = 1:
   k = n % 10
   z= 0
   w=0
   w = k * (pow ( 2, z)) + w
   z = z+1
   n/10
print w
```

Comment: can you show an example of how it's not working? are you getting an error? if so, what's the traceback?

Comment: also, do you know about `int(number, base)`? `int('10010', 2) == 18`

Comment: It takes a long time to run, no real output when running a small number like 1011 in 5 minutes

Comment: @mhlester How would I use that to convert a user input? EDIT: GOT IT

Comment: @user3281550 - He's saying that your whole script can be reduced to just: `print int(raw_input(' '), 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you used `=` for a comparison test.  Instead, I think that you want to use `!=` (not equal):

```
while n != 1:
```

`=` is only used for assignment.

---

Also, the line:

```
n/10
```

does nothing.  Instead, it should be:

```
n /= 10
```

which is equivalent to:

```
n = n / 10
```